# issues on Orientation iOS

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, uiwindow, uideviceorientation

I'm developing an app that supports only portrait orientation as written in my Info.plist file. 
    But when i Rotate the device the status bar rotates but the views don't.
    I don't use the InterfaceBuilder to set my views and initial window, I do it pro-grammatically writing:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

   self.window.rootViewController = myRootViewController;

   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}
```

In all my views there is the method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I do that by setting "Portrait (bottom home button)" in the "Supported interface orientation" field in the Info.plist file.

One other method is removing the default implementation of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` from all your view controllers.

Comment: Yup, if you remove *shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:*, your views should not try to rotate at all anymore.

Comment: some other thing is hindering here, as I tried it and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

to your : `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

in the AppDelegate.

Hope this helps !

Comment: NO. Doesn't solve my problem.
The status bar still rotates and when the UINavigationController pushes an UIViewController (with the device in landscape mode) the UINavigationBar resize in height but the view is always in portrait